# Trying to figure out the best approach to perform CRUD operations for a slightly complex SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, model-view-controller

I'm currently working on a C# dot net core MVC project with an MSSQL database back end. I've gone with a data first approach. Here's a simplified sample of my dbcontext.

//dbcontext//

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace redux.web.Models
{
    public partial class assetsdbContext : DbContext
    {
        public assetsdbContext()
        {
        }

        public assetsdbContext(DbContextOptions<assetsdbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AssetType> AssetType { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Assets> Assets { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Cpu> Cpu { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Memory> Memory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Pcdetails> Pcdetails { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AssetType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Assets>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.AssetNo)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.AssetTypeId).HasColumnName("AssetTypeID");

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.PcdetailsId).HasColumnName("PCDetailsID");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Cpu>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("CPU");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Memory>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Pcdetails>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("PCDetails");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Cpuid).HasColumnName("CPUID");

                entity.Property(e => e.MemoryId).HasColumnName("MemoryID");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My problem now is how to handle PC Details when entering a new asset as there will be PCs and non-pc assets. I'm thinking I'd need use AssetType maybe in a if statement within the create method? or can I design the database in a better way? Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `0:1` foreign key, so that the primary key of `PCAsset` and `NonPCAsset` is the also the primary key of `Asset`, along with `AssetType` column, which is fixed (computed column) per child table. This is sometimes known as Table-per-Type Inheritance

Comment: @Charlieface Just for clarification, There isn't an entity called NonPCAsset. The assets table contains both assets that will have PC details and assets that are not PCs which do not require PC details. The entities are **Assets**, **AssetType**, **CPU**, **Memory** and **PCDetails**

Comment: My point was you may consider splitting up the two different types of Assets into separate types. I'm not entirely sure what your question was to be honest, it was just a suggestion

Comment: @Charlieface Oh OK, I didn't think of that! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would include a column in the PCDetails that links to the Assets table as a Foreign Key.  You can add business logic to your UI to display the options to change/add/delete the details of the Asset is of the Type "PC".

Comment: I was considering putting the logic in the UI, but then I remembered, that's bad practice. :)